# Apache status question.

Tags: apache2

Anyone can explain this  lines:
120.132.50.135  127.0.1.1:80    GET http://some domain/ HTTP/1.1

is it normal, or my server is hacked?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty normal entry in your apache access log. People try all sorts of things while trying to connect to web servers.  You'll see a lot more detailed events if you go digging.  For example, you'll see people trying to access specific files that might be potentially compromised.  You may see a bunch of requests for a wordpress location, where you don't run wordpress.  People scour the web for nefarious reasons, all day long.

I tried to make a request similar to that.

```
$telnet localhost 80
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET http://some domain/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Here is what is in the log.

```
::1 - - [01/Apr/2016:15:56:00 -0400] "GET http://some domain/" 200 1045
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Recently I  have many connections from China, and got suspicious.

Comment: @krastanov There are lots of bots running from China